# resizing embeded page content to view port

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, viewport

I am using bootstrap.
Due to viewport problem, i cannot use carousel swiping on mobile device.

https://f40e78d2360ec7809a8c04445fd688e46c3a22d4.googledrive.com/host/0B_bqKoIkDjvKWVNkaXVPQ2QtYm8/shaiabs/gthub.html

PageSpeed Insight says: The page content is 390 CSS pixels wide, but the viewport is only 375 CSS pixels wide. The following elements fall outside the viewport
The element `<div class="embed"></div>` falls outside the viewport.

It is an embedded contact form.

I dont understand where and what changes should i make:

in the embed code or in the contact form

Comment: u talking about vertical slide?????????????

Comment: horizontal, try opening it on your mobile device

Comment: yes i fix it use this css. check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use this css in your stylesheet in @media 

center-block
    {
    width:100% !important;
    }
.elegantshadow
    {
        padding:0px !important
    }
```

Comment: sorry, was editing the page. When i remove this, the problem is gone <!--visible xtra small screen --> <iframe class="center-block embed-responsive-item hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm" src="******.github.io/contact-form/index.html"; style="border: 0px none; height: 500px; margin-top: -50px; margin-bottom: -150px; width: 350px;"></iframe> but i want to display the form.

Comment: make a class for <iframe class="">  and give width:100% !important;

i have only file that you showing i dont know what you really doing.

Comment: if you dont know how can solve then send me your file i solve it. without any cost

Comment: here it is https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_bqKoIkDjvKNG4ya2RaYjhRem8&usp=drive_web

external css: freelancer.css

do have a look at user experience here: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ff40e78d2360ec7809a8c04445fd688e46c3a22d4.googledrive.com%2Fhost%2F0B_bqKoIkDjvKWVNkaXVPQ2QtYm8%2Fshaillabs%2Fgithub.html&tab=mobile

Comment: http://dev1.techencephalon.com/test-gk/ 


check this link now i think your problem solve

Comment: if yes then tell me. i send you your files bcz i m going now

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwnfu4A_9xNSQVVISE1ENDQ3MUU/view?usp=sharing



this is you file